# Check http_referer htaccess swf files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have some .swf files and i want to know if it's possible to check with htaccess the HTTP_REFERER to check if they are coming from my website.

The .swf files are emmbed in my website but i dont want the people to be able to share the swf so easy. Because they can copy the URL and share it with their friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can block via referer using mod_rewrite. If your site is: example.com, then in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/
RewriteRule \.swf$ - [L,F,NC]
```